# Using sed to remove string between two other stings in specific column

Tags: sed

I want sed to look at only the first column of a tab-delimited file and remove everything between some string and the first tab for all rows. Sorry if this is repetitive, have searched other entries and cannot seem to find anything quite right.

For example, input:

```
blah-a_blah-b.13_blah-x_blah-y        0       0       0       0       0       17.983559
```

desired output:

```
blah-a_blah-b.13        0       0       0       0       0       17.983559
```

Tried unsuccessfully various iterations of below:

```
sed -i 's/\(\.[0-9]\).*\([^\t]\)//1' file
```

Advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in `gnu-sed`:

```bash
sed -E 's/^([^\t]*\.[0-9]+)[^\t]+/\1/' file

blah-a_blah-b.13    0   0   0   0   0   17.983559
```

For non-gnu sed use:

```bash
sed -E 's/^([^[:blank:]]*\.[0-9]+)[^[:blank:]]+/\1/' file
```